# finding UMVUE $P ( X_1> t)$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Suppose $ X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d. random variables with density: $$f(x_i;\theta)=\theta x_i^{-2}$$ $$x_i>\theta$$$$\theta>0$$

The smallest order statistic $X_{(1)}$  is sufficient and complete for $\theta$ .
We would estimate $P( X_1> t)$ for constant $t> 0$. From the fact that
$I ( X_1> t)$ is an unbiased estimator for $P ( X_1>t)$ , find the estimator UMVUE
$P ( X_1> t)$.

to Find UMVUE estimator is not an easy task. How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Would those who voted to close this explain why?

Answer (score 1):

The Lehmann–Scheffé theorem says that the conditional expected value of any unbiased estimator given the value of a complete sufficient statistic is the UMVUE.  So the first question is whether there is a complete sufficient statistic.  The joint density is
\begin{align}
f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) & = \theta^n x_1^{-2} \cdots x_n^{-2} = \theta^n(x_1\cdots x_n)^{-2} \quad \text{for } x_1,\ldots,x_n>\theta \\[10pt]
& = \theta^n(x_1\cdots x_n)^{-2} I_{[\theta,\infty)}(\min\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}).
\end{align}
This has one factor, namely $\theta^nI_{[\theta,\infty)}(\min\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\})$, that depends on $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ only through $\min\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$, and another factor (in this case $(x_1\cdots x_n)^{-2}$) that does not depend on $\theta$.  This is a Fisher factorization; therefore $\min\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$ is sufficient for $\theta$.

If that statistic is complete, then the UMVUE will be the conditional expected value
$$
\operatorname{E}( I(X_1>t) \mid \min\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}) = \Pr(X_1>t\mid \min\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}).
$$
(That that random variable is a statistic depends on the fact that $\min$ is sufficient.)

Notice that if $\min\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}>t$ then *a fortiori* $X_1>t$.  Hence $\Pr(X_1>t\mid \min\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}=x) = 1$ if $x>t$.

If $x<t$, then how do we find $\Pr(X_1>t\mid \min\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}=x)$?

\begin{align}
& \Pr(X_1>t\mid \min = x) \\[10pt]
= {} & \Pr(X_1=\min)\Pr(X_1>t\mid\min=x) + \Pr(X_1\ne\min)\Pr(X_1>t\mid\min=x) \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac 1 n \cdot 0 + \frac{n-1}n\cdot \Big( \cdots\cdots \Big)
\end{align}

[to be continued$\,\ldots\ldots$]

Comment: Can you continue your answer ?

Comment: Hello.  I'll be back shortly$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: can you please finish this problem ?